# Is there a noticeable difference between a 23.1 x 15.4mm and a 23.6 x 15.8mm sensor size?

Tags: dslr, sensor-size

Is there a noticeable difference between a 23.1 x 15.4 mm and a 23.6 x 15.8 mm sensor size when accompanied by a prime lens of 1.4F?

After how large a change in the numbers does the difference get noticeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aperture won't matter at all — f/1.4 will be the same in any case. *Focal length* could be considered to matter if you measure what you can fit in the frame with a ruler, but even then the *percent* difference due to different sensor sizes stays the same (which is why the concept of "crop factor" works).

This is super-easy to calculate because the difference is directly proportional to focal length. That means you can divide one dimension by the other to get a meaningful value for the difference. In the case you give, 23.6 / 23.1 = about 1.02, or a two-percent difference.

So simply put, **the difference in this case is barely noticeable**. If you overlaid two images taken from the same location you might be able to tell, but slight differences in position and framing — and variance in labeling of focal length — are going to be a much bigger deal.

You can decide for yourself what you consider a meaningful difference. 10% is probably enough that you can see it but it won't real make much difference. At 20%, you'll probably think, yeah, that matters.

I highly recommend you try the on-paper exercise I lay out [in this answer on angle-of-view](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/5924/1943). In addition to the examples I use, also try the exact measurements for sensor size you want to compare, and this will become directly clear in a way that's going to be more meaningful than thinking about abstract numbers.

Comment: additional thought: many viewfinders only cover 90 to 95% of the scene, more than twice that difference.