# Thread size and filter diameter

Tags: lens, canon

I am trying to buy my husband a gift from photojojo.  He has a Canon DSLR.  It's the EF-55-250mm.  I have found a white balance lens cap that needs a size and the photojojo site says to look for the size on the outer rim of the lens.  There are two numbers that I think it could be, 55mm and 58mm.  My question is- are the thread size and the filter diameter the same thing?  It's not clear on the lens because the 55mm actually reads "15-55mm" on one of his lenses and 55-250mm on the other AND there's a spot on BOTH of them that have a no symbol and then a "58mm" in another spot.

Comment: Get the 58mm white balance lens cap and it should work on both of the lenses you have mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The thread size is the filter diameter.

The other number is the focal length. This corresponds to the [angle of view](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/what-is-angle-of-view-in-photography) of the lens. The range of numbers in both cases is because they are zoom lenses, and those two "kit" lenses are designed as a sort of matched pair, so one starts where the other one leaves off, and that just happens to be at 55mm.

The "no symbol", by the way, *isn't* a no symbol. It's a [diameter symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%8C%80#Diameter_symbol), ⌀.