# Understanding Lenses and the Focal length and Distance of Shooting

Tags: lens

Suppose i want to make a Picture of a Tiger,in the National park or in wild life safari,and to  fill in the Frame with my Aps-c Eos Camera with  Focal Length at 300mm,how close or far i need to Approach the subject,I would Like to Know the Distance in meters or in Foots Roughly?

Answer (score 2):

There are many species of tigers and they vary in size. Suppose that the tiger in mind is a male [Bengal tiger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengal_tiger). They have an avarage nose-to-tail length of 270 to 310 cm.

Using a 300 mm lens on an Canon APS-C camera will give you a horizontal [angle-of-view](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/what-is-angle-of-view-in-photography) of about 4.3 degrees. To fill the frame with a subject measuring 3 meters horizontally you'd have to stand 40 meters away. Depending of how you want to frame the shot you might have to move closer/further away.

There are many tools that you can use to calculate this distance available on the Internet. [This](http://www.tawbaware.com/maxlyons/calc.htm) one for example.