# Which lens should I get for a person holding a quilt under fluorescent lighting?

Tags: lens, product-photography

What would be the best lens for my canon T6s for taking a picture of a person holding a quilt average size 90 by 100? The room has fluorescent lighting, and there is very little outside light because the blinds are mostly shut during the meeting.

Comment: How big is the room? 90 by 100 *whats* for the quilt? mm? km? In any case, you may want to read [What is “angle of view” in photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/what-is-angle-of-view-in-photography)

Comment: This question mixes up light and lens.  It also does not provide enough information to answer usefully.  There is the stray mention of a meeting-how does that influence what you want?

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about the florescent lighting, shoot in RAW and make sure that the florescent lighting is overpowering any other light sources. The lens really doesn't come into play if the concern is the florescents.

If you have competing light sources your options are to turn some lights off, modify them to match(gels or with different bulbs), or to overpower them with a flash. Doing it in post is quite difficult or impossible.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options.

**1)** If you are concerned about the light... look for a wide aperture lens. 1.8 perhaphs?

**2)** If you are concerned about a small room and the subject too close to the camera, use a wide lens.

**3)** If you are concerned about taking a product photography that sells your product... discard the room with fluorescent lights, and buy some speedlights and bounce them in the ceiling, and open the blinds so they cast interesting light and shadows.

A product shoot is not done during a meeting. But you probably could make a meeting during a product shoot.

Answer (score 0):

Light temperature (Fluorescent light, Day light, Tungsten, and so on) is NOT one of the criteria for choosing a lens.

The light temperature should only be taken into consideration when you're setting the camera (white balance, light temperature, or whatever other names there might be for this setting) and when you are post-processing the picture.

You chose a lens depending on what and how you want to photograph.
Is it a close-up? Is it a macro? Do you need a shallow depth of field? Do you need to get as much of the scene in the picture?