# What's the field of view for LIDAR in iPhone Pro 12 and iPhone Pro Max?

Tags: field-of-view, iphone, 3d

It looks like the angles aren't quite 67.3 x 53.06 degrees as this answer suggests: [What is the Angle of View of the iPhone XS rear camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106509). At least the point clouds I get look better for 75 degrees of horizontal FoV rather than 67.3.