# What is the Field of View (FoV) of iPhone XS Max?

Tags: iphone, field-of-view

What the field of view (FoV) of iPhone XS Max rear cameras?

Comment: Perhaps this [link](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106509/what-is-the-angle-of-view-of-the-iphone-xs-rear-camera) will answer you're question.

Answer (score 1):

DxOmark reports for the iPhone XS (and XS Max, which have the same cameras) a 35mm equivalent of 26 and 52mm ([link](https://www.dxomark.com/apple-iphone-xs-max-review-flagship-imaging-power/)).

This corresponds to a horizontal FoV of 69.4 and 38.2 degrees.