# How can a 24-70mm and a 10-22mm both be "wide angle" lenses?

Tags: lens, terminology, focal-length, wide-angle, ultra-wide

I've been looking at a 10-22mm lens for my Canon T2i. I've also come across some other "wide angle" lenses, like the Sigma 24-70mm F2.8.

I don't understand how a wide angle lens can have such high numbers. The kit lens is 18-55mm; 18 is lower than 24 — so does that mean the kit lens is a "wide angle lens?

Comment: "wide angle" is not a technical term, it has no precise definition - you could ask how can a Humvee and the space shuttle transporter both be "wide" vehicles

Comment: @Matt Grum — that's easy. They're both wider than 8' 6". :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Traditionally, [lenses wider than 24mm on full-frame are "ultra-wide"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/327/what-is-an-ultra-wide-lens). On a smaller-sensor Canon DSLR, a 15mm lens provides that same field of view (16mm on Nikon, Pentax, or Sony; 12mm on Olympus/Panasonic). So on an APS-C camera, a 20mm lens would be "wide" but not "ultra-wide" — but with the increased field of view of full frame, that would fall under ultra-wide.

On full frame, a 35mm lens is wide angle (but not ultra-wide); that same lens would be ["normal" on an APS-C camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/what-focal-length-gives-a-normal-field-of-view-on-aps-c-cameras).

In either case, yes, the 18-55mm kit lens is a wide-angle lens. On a crop-factor DSLR, that nicely covers a reasonably wide angle, through normal, up to a moderate "portrait-length" telephoto.

(On some systems, some lenses designed for APS-C cameras won't work at all on full frame. Or, they'll work but with poor performance in the corners — and on Nikon, for example, this is compensated-for by automatically cropping-out the edges when a designed-for-APS-C lens is attached. But it's pretty much universal that full-frame lenses will work on APS-C.)

Comment: So what you're saying is that if I have a 24mm lens that works on both cameras, the camera will determine if the lens is "wide angle" or not - is that right? Any thoughts on the best entry-level ultra wide for an APS-C ?

Comment: Well, technically, a 24mm lens is wide angle on both APS-C and full-frame — I'm not sure if there's a perfectly agreed-upon upper limit to "wide angle", but 35mm is a traditional wide angle lens for full frame, and 24mm on APS-C is right around that. But yeah, the camera format (sensor size) determines whether a given focal length is wide angle or not.

Comment: As for the recommendation — the kit lens (for any brand) is almost certainly the best value in a basic _entry-level_ wide angle lens. But if you want to go wider than that, you'll need something else, and I don't have a lot of expertise there.

Comment: If I see through the viewfinder with a 50mm-F1.8 on my APS-C camera, things appear to have no magnification (1:1). So on crop, everything below 50mm would be wide I guess

Comment: @rompetroll See [this](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26295/why-does-a-50mm-lens-appear-to-give-a-human-field-of-view-rather-than-a-normal) on 50mm lenses and viewfinder magnification. In general, no: the accepted definition of wide/normal/long has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 7):

All of the lenses you mentioned are wide angle lenses; the distinction is that there are degrees of wide-angle. On your T2i, that 24–70mm lens at 24mm will be a moderate wide angle. The 10–22mm will be an ultra-wide (maybe ultra-ultra-wide?) at 10mm, and go to a more moderate wide angle at 22mm.

Mike Johnston wrote an amusing but opinionated article called [Uses and Applications of 35mm lenses](http://photo.net/mjohnston/column57/) that attempts to break down the various categories of wide angle lenses. The focal lengths are for a full-frame camera, but you'll get the idea.

If you're looking to go really wide, Ken Rockwell’s  article [How to Use Ultra-Wide Lenses](http://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/how-to-use-ultra-wide-lenses.htm) is a strong introduction to the significant challenges and rewards that you'll see from using ultra-wide lenses.

Comment: +1 — Ken Rockwell at his best. And the Mike Johnston article is quite funny (but I'll bet he wouldn't write that today!).

Answer (score 1):

"Wide", "normal", and "telephoto" depend not just on the focal length, but on the format size as well.  In the full-frame (35mm) world, any focal length shorter than 35mm or so counts as "wide angle" in that it captures a wider field of view than a "normal" 50mm lens (which roughly reproduces the field of view we see with our eyes).

In the large-format world (4" x 5"), a 50mm focal length is on the wide to ultra-wide side.  In the APS-C world, that same focal length is slightly telephoto, and 35mm is "normal" (or close to it).